# ¿Se utiliza la palabra "anabolena"? ¿Cómo de común o frecuente es su uso?

Tags: palabras-raras, diccionarios

El Diccionario de la lengua española de la Real Academia Española incluyó en 1970 [**anabolena**](https://dle.rae.es/anabolena) con la definición:

> 1. f. Mujer alocada y trapisondista.

mientras que la definición del [**Diccionario de americanismos**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=anabolena) es ligeramente diferente:

> adj/sust. RD. Referido a una mujer, entrometida, enredadora.

Sin embargo, apenas aparecen casos en el CORDE, CREA, CDH o CORPES XXI.

¿Es una palabra de uso frecuente hoy en día? ¿Con la acepción del DLE o la del Diccionario de americanismos? Y si no lo es, ¿por qué entró en el DLE tan recientemente y no figura  como "desusada", "p. us" o con una marca análoga?

Answer (score 3):

La verdad es que los resultados de "anabolena" en Google solo parecen hacer un uso metalingüístico de la palabra (es decir, la usan para comentar lo que significa), o bien hacen referencia a nombres de usuario, de archivo, *hashtags*, etc. Incluso parece que "Anabolena" es un nombre propio. No encuentro resultados que la usen en un contexto apropiado según su significado.

En [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=anabolena&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=21&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) el uso es también principalmente metalingüístico, aunque algún ejemplo he encontrado:

> *Estaba allí por mor de un pleito mayor con una sirena, y él estaba de la parte de la anabolena, y vestía un gabán de pardomonte deslustrado por los temporales.*

Este ejemplo es de 1957, y es de los primeros que se recogen, no parece ser una palabra mucho más antigua (los casos que aparecen a partir de 1700 hacen referencia a "AnaBolena" como nombre propio).

En la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España veo el siguiente texto:

> *[...] porque la soberanía reside esencialmente en las naciones, y si estas pueden [...] hacer de Anabolena una Reyna, tambien pueden hacer de una Reyna una Anabolena.*
>
> **El Zurriago (Madrid).** 1822, n.º 43, [página 3](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003938643&page=3&search=anabolena&lang=es).

Frases como esta podrían haber dado lugar al origen de *anabolena* como sustantivo, pero no lo tengo claro. Lo curioso es que a partir de ahí, los casos de *anabolena* como nombre común ya llegan al siglo XXI, aunque no puedo citar ejemplos completos por ser de acceso restringido en la web. Lo que sí es que hay pocos, uno de 2003, otro de 2008 y otro de 2019.

Así pues, sí, se podría decir que el sustantivo *anabolena* es poco usado al menos en España, que es donde he hecho el estudio, aunque para nada se puede decir que esté en desuso si se encuentran casos tan recientes.